# How to make 'toast' on Gear2

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I found [here](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-gear) in "UI Design Guidelines for Gear 2" document information about pop-ups, that we can use the following types of pop-ups:
- Information
- Confirmation
- Alerts
- Progress
- Processes
- **Toasts**

I'm interested in the last one: **toasts**, but i can't find anything how to provide them.
Do you have any step-by-step solutions/samples that could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of question, you should use the sample project "WearableWidget"

You can add this to your HTML for toast, and there is plenty of other exemple of pop-up:

```
<div class="ui-popup-toast">
        Saving contacts to sim on Samsung 
</div>
```